Unable to read change stream from mongodb using Debezium connector for mongodb
I get the following error on any update on the mongo database
{
  "timestamp" : "13-11-2024 T 11:41:12.255Z",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "thread" : "debezium-mongodbconnector-${connector-name}-change-event-source-coordinator",
  "mdc" : {
    "dbz.connectorName" : "{connector name as in ${topic.prefix}}",
    "dbz.connectorType" : "MongoDB",
    "dbz.taskId" : "0",
    "dbz.connectorContext" : "streaming"
  },
  "logger" : "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnections",
  "message" : "Error while attempting to Reading change stream: 'com.mongodb.client.model.changestream.SplitEvent com.mongodb.client.model.changestream.ChangeStreamDocument.getSplitEvent()'",
  "context" : "default",
  "exception": "**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.client.model.changestream.SplitEvent com.mongodb.client.model.changestream.ChangeStreamDocument.getSplitEvent()****'\r\n\tat 
io.debezium.connector.mongodb.events.SplitEventHandler.handle(SplitEventHandler.java:34)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.processChangeStreamDocument(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:145)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$readChangeStream$1(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:113)\r
\n\tat java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.readChangeStream(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:113)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$0(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:85)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnection.lambda$execute$0(MongoDbConnection.java:89)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnection.execute(MongoDbConnection.java:105)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.connection.MongoDbConnection.execute(MongoDbConnection.java:88)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:84)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(MongoDbStreamingChangeEventSource.java:37)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:312)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:203)\r
\n\tat io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:143)\r
\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\r
\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)\r\n"
}

I am able to get an initial snapshot of the events in mongoDB but on doing some changes in the database, it doesn't give real-time events and gives the above error. What might be missing?
I tried changing modes to no_data(earlier never) and always, but it didn't work.

That looks like a version problem.  SplitEvent is new in MongoDB 7.0, what version of the driver are you running?

I see that the method is present in mongodb-driver-core dependency. I've included 4.6.0 version of the same

See how? Is that dependency on your classpath?

Got the fix, exclude mongodb-driver if it is being included from any other dependency (it comes from debezium-connector-mongodb) and add it as such
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for getting real-time events, when it was giving NoSuchMethodError for changeStream.getSplitEvent() -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

Adding the bson dependency solved it
